# Flag for users without any unlocked groups

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have a convoluted user system that I'm dealing with and I'm trying to find out what groups a user is part of, and also whether or not ALL of those groups are in a locked state.

Here's the basics of the schema I'm using.

users

```
+--------+
| userId |
+--------+
| 1      |
+--------+
| 2      |
+--------+
```

user_groups

```
+--------+---------+
| userId | groupId |
+--------+---------+
| 1      | 100     |
+--------+---------+
| 2      | 200     |
+--------+---------+
| 2      | 300     |
+--------+---------+
```

groups

```
+---------+---------+
| groupId | locked  |
+---------+---------+
| 100     | 1       |
+---------+---------+
| 200     | 1       |
+---------+---------+
| 300     | 0       |
+---------+---------+
```

so given this example, user 2 belongs to groups 200, and 300.

group 200 is locked, while group 300 is not.

What I'm looking for is a list of users, their groups (separated by a comma), and whether or not ALL of their groups are locked.

```
+--------+----------+--------+
| userId | groupIds | locked |
+--------+----------+--------+
| 1      | 100      | 1      |
+--------+----------+--------+
| 2      | 200, 300 | 0      |
+--------+----------+--------+
```

The query I wrote selects `group.locked` but that only tells me the status of the first group selected by the join, right? I'm also not confident that I'm using grouping correctly.

```
select
users.userId,
group_concat(groups.groupId) groupIds,
group.locked
from users
left join user_groups
    on user_groups.userId = users.userId
left join groups
    on groups.groupId = user_groups.groupId
group by groups.groupId
```

Comment: you can use case logic for that.. `case locked when 0 then 0 else 1 end` also you should group by userID

Comment: you will want to group by userID and not groupID here.   Be careful with MySQL groupings, if you don't get your group by correct, MySQL will do the wrong grouping and not return an error.  General rule, group by the columns, not the aggregates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just use [`min`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_min) - if one `0` (unlocked) exists, the result would be `0`, and if all of them are `1` (locked), the result would be `1`:

```
select users.userId,
       group_concat(groups.groupId) groupIds,
       min(group.locked)
from users
left join user_groups
    on user_groups.userId = users.userId
left join groups
    on groups.groupId = user_groups.groupId
group by users.userId
```

(Note that the grouping should be done by `userId` and not `gorupId`)

Comment: +1 I was thinking along the lines of a `where not exists` subquery, but `min` is much simpler!

Comment: fantastic, thank you! `min` also works for another column of ours (N and Y) so its perfect.

Answer (score 1):

Alternate to minimum logic:

Lets add another join to this to discover locked.  This is a simple script to pick out users that have at least one unlocked user_group

```
select user_groups.userID 
from user_groups ug
inner join groups
on groups.groupId = user_groups.groupId
where locked = 0
group by user_groups.userid
```

combine the two statements with a left join and a case to read the locked status

```
select
users.userId,
group_concat(groups.groupId) groupIds,
case when a.user_ID is null  then 1 else 0 end
from users
left join user_groups
on user_groups.userId = users.userId
left join groups
(    select user_groups.userID 
    from user_groups ug
    inner join groups
    on groups.groupId = user_groups.groupId
    where locked = 0
    group by user_groups.userid
) a ona.userID = users.userID
on groups.groupId = user_groups.groupId
group by groups.userID
```

Honestly...minimum logic is probably better...this is the left join version of a where in(subquery), which works better on mysql.